# WebSockets to Python "Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value"

Tags: python, websocket, handshake

I'm having some trouble getting my websockets to accept the response using python.

I'm using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:50705");
});
```

To call a python socket which is calling this function:

```
def resolveKey(self, key):
    key = bytes(key, "utf-8") + bytes("258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11", "utf-8")
    key = hashlib.sha1(key).hexdigest()
    key = base64.b64encode(bytes(key, "utf-8"))
    return key
```

And these are the headers:

REQUEST

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:127.0.0.1:50705
Origin:null
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:iqQ1q0W6FoAJXvrCAbCqHQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
```

RESPONSE

```
Connection:Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:NThmZDY4Y2YxZjc1Y2VkYTA3YWJmNmRmYTc3OWMyZDMyZGY2MmZjZQ==
Upgrade:WebSocket
```

I've taken the value, manually applied the magic key, sha1'd it and then base64 encoded it and the value appears to be correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: On a side note, is this whole process necessary? It seems like an added complication for no reason.

Comment: I have absolutely the same issue with my PHP server code: same "Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value" error, while I'm doing exactly same operations to get that Sec-WebSocket-Accept value. Posting my own questions...

Comment: @FancyJohn I eventually worked this out. Every post you can find will tell you to read https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 Do it. You don't have to read it all, just skim until you find what you need but it details every step. Also PHP probably isn't the right choice for a web socket server. If you've got some flexibility, use node.js

Comment: I think it is necessary, to prevent an attack.